# How to find time-domain description of the system given only h[n] values?

Tags: frequency-domain

I'm puzzled by this exercise, I can find \$y[n]\$ given other data but not only with '\$h\$' values. Any help will be appreciated.

EXERCISE:

System impulse response:

$\begin {align}
h[0] &= 5 \
h[1] &= 3 \
h[2] &= 1 \

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. We need you to show that you have put forth a substantial effort to solve this yourself, show us **all** of your work, and then as a specific question.

Comment: Since the impulse response is non zero for finite number of samples, this appears to be an FIR filter. The time domain equation can be written down trivially. It will be of the format \$y[n]= a_0 x[n] + a_1 x[n-1] + a_2 x[n-3]\$. Use x[n] as the unit impulse to workout the values of the coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a fundamental point of signal processing.  An impulse response *is* a complete time-domain description of a linear system.  Given a system \$y = h(x)\$, where \$h\$ is linear and time-invariant (as yours is), \$y[n] = x[n] \star h[n]\$, where \$\star\$ is the convolution operator.

I suggest looking for "convolution" in your lecture notes or your book's table of contents or index.  You may have to backtrack a bit from there before reading forward again -- but you should get a full description.

Answer (score 1):

Since the impulse response is non zero for finite number of samples, this appears to be an FIR filter. The time domain equation can be written down trivially. It will be of the format \$y[n]= a_0 x[n] + a_1 x[n-1] + a_2 x[n-3] + \dots + a_k x[n-k]\$. Use x[n] as the unit impulse (then y[n] will be h[n]) to workout the values of the coefficients.